# Syntax javascript error missing ) after argument list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I get the Syntax missing ) error

```
$(document).ready(function changeText() {

    var p =     document.getElementById('bidprice');

    var btn = document.getElementById('paybtn');

    var txt = document.getElementById('theText');
    btn.onclick( p.textContent = txt.value; );

});
```

what exactly is the wrong thing  I have tried looking at my syntax seems okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `;`, and `onclick` property should be a function.

```
btn.onclick( p.textContent = txt.value; );
                                      ^
```

Remove it, and wrap everything in a function:

```
btn.onclick = function(){
    p.textContent = txt.value;
};
```

Comment: wait it doesn't persist thanks a  lot , however the value  retrived is empty is empty

Comment: @ElijahCorleone, you would need to create a fiddle to illustrate the issue :)

Comment: @ElijahCorleone, you can accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are trying to name your function in the parameter passed into 'ready'.

First line should be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

Comment: Nope. You can also do var outer=function inner (){} inner is just acessible inside of the code, making it possible to have anonymous recurisve functions, it doesnt matter if a function is anonymous or not, its always a function...